# Why does C not execute anything after the 1st for loop?

Tags: c, for-loop, runtime

I have just started learning some basic C, and I came up with no error  while trying to run this particular snippet of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
float soln[5];
int a[4] = {2,3,-11,-6},d,e,r=1;
for (float y =-10.0000; y<=10.0000; y += 0.1)
{
    d = a[0]*y*y*y + a[1]*y*y +a[2]*y + a[3];
    if (d == 0)
    {
        printf("\n SOLUTION \t");
        soln[e] = y;
        printf("%f",soln[e]);
        e+=1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n %d NO SOLUTION %d \n",r,d);
        r+=1;
    }
}
printf("ok");
for( int p; p<3;p++)
    {
        printf(" %f ",soln[p]);
    }
}
```

What I am attempting to do is to try and solve a 3 degree polynomial equation and to store the solution in another array, which I would like to display using the aforementioned second for loop. However, after the execution of the first for loop, the program just straight up ends with the printf statement giving me Ok as the last output. Any suggestions/ help with this would be really appreciated :D

Comment: `for( int p; p<3;p++)`. Need to initialise `p` to some value there.

Comment: oh ok ill try that

Comment: `soln[e] = y;` Look at the value of `e` (it is not intialised). Tip: Learn to do basic debugging. Run your program in a debugger and step through it line by line, examining the variables and program flow as it runs.

Comment: @kaylum will do. Thanks for the tip :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never initialized p.

Try: for(int p = 0; p < 3; p++) {
...
}

Comment: Did you initialize the variable `d` and `e`@chcheetah

Comment: @Mr.Chip, no I did not. Should I initialize those too?

Comment: I think you should have a try. Both `d` and `e` should be initialized to zero.

Comment: `d` does not strictly need to be initialised as it is set before it is used.

Comment: Try printing out each variable as you increment through the first loop, because I don't think it's doing what you think it is, and as a result the second one just print the cryptic values stored in the soln array. @chcheetah

Comment: I initialised e and d as @Mr. Chip said and now it works perfectly! Thanks guys!

Comment: @kekag I tried that too its working now thanks :)